# Paste from MS Word document to a Web Form

Tags: webforms, ms-word, text-formatting

What is the most common way people preserve basic formatting elements like bold emphasis and italics when copying to a textarea from an MS Word document.  I noticed that Gmail does this well and StackOverflow does not.  Are there common frameworks that do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably one of the most common rich text controls used is [FCKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) (now, thank God, named CKEditor). It does a really great job at preserving format when pasting from Word.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for the advice.  FCKEditor is quite a terrible name!

Answer (score 3):

We use [FreeTextBox](http://freetextbox.com/) as a replacement for multiline textarea's in ASP.NET, the rich text entered here retains its formatting when cut and pasted into word.